# Smooth Scrolling in graphics -how to achieve it

Tags: blackberry

I am trying to draw Text,lines etc in the graphics of the manager,Problem that i am presently facing is that

If i have the content more than that of the display width,I am not able to scroll it,

I tried using focusfield with just focus on it,Problem that i face on using this,whenever i switch to some other manager,I am getting focus stuck in the focus field,

So anyone help me in achieving a smooth scrolling in the graphics of the Manager.

Regards

Rakesh shankar.P

Comment: Maybe extend ScrollView?

Comment: Hi,I want to do it for 4.5 and above,ScrollView will be there from 6.0 and above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I increased the size of emptyfield ,added the focus to it,thats it.